# Turn very old ductless AC wall unit into smart AC

Tags: circuit-design, esp8266

I have a very old Burnham ductless AC wall unit that I would like to be able to control via a sonoff (esp8266).  I have modified the sonoff to isolate the relay, separating it from the main line so that it will act as a switch to complete a circuit.  I'm really only concerned with turning on cool mode, not fan mode.  I'm wondering if it would be as simple as shorting out the two solder joints (see red line in second photo to which I believe is cool mode).  I have been too afraid to short it out on my own to test my theory, so I've come here as a newbie for expert advice.  I'm hoping to just tap into those joints and connect to my sonoff relay to turn the unit on/off.  I'm a little concerned though trying to introduce another means of turning the unit on.  I'm worried about the "off" mode which appears to be completing some sort of circuit (I follow it up to something labeled 'DV'?).  Can I interject (short out) the cool mode joints while the switch is still in off mode?  Attached are some photos of the wired remote and the back of the circuit board (back of the remote once screws are removed).

[image: Here is the front of the remote where you can see the cool mode I want to be able to turn on/off]

[image: Here in red is what I believe would turn on cool mode?]

Comment: That mode switch has 10 terminals, I cannot say which ones are connected in each mode, but with slide switches usually  each column is independent.

Comment: if you can find the model number of the switch and then a data-sheet for it we can figure out what contact pattern is needed for each mode, and then sort out a way to mimic that using relays.  else you're going to have to measure it out-of-circuit, either by removing it, or by cutting tracks - both approaches risk damaging the remote if you fumble it.

Comment: @Jasen I can't find any documentation for this particular unit, its probably 25-30+ years old.  Burnham B181WHEB is what I believe the model number is.  I also considered adding a sonoff device at the main line and just leave the remote set to Cool and toggle the power to the unit with the sonoff; less risky than damaging the remote.  I just don't know how many amps the unit draws as there are limitations on the sonoff device.  10A on the basic sonoff and 16A on a few other models.  Is there a way to determine how many amps the unit draws?  Or is this a bad approach.

Comment: looking  at the plug and/or the fuse may give some hints as to the number of amps, but compressor motors often take many more amps while starting than they do when running

Comment: Notice that there are 14 soldered pins for a 3-position switch? without seeing the other side of the PCB and the "working bits" of the switch, it would be a TERRIBLE IDEA to assume **anything** about which pins should be shorted for any specific switch setting (well, anything besides that you don't know anything...lol)

Comment: it sounds fine. that board is low-voltage. run through it with a continuity checker and verify the switches do what you think. if they do, you can easily and safely "short" them with a relay to mimic the physical switch.

Answer (score 2):

This stinks like smoke, fire and death. Stop as long as you still can.

Hire a local pro electrician for the job. Probably he refuses but offers a legal and safe solution.

You have no circuit diagrams and technical specs. Nobody healthy headed person will cheer you on to continue this effort.

Stop, while you can!!!